# sas string converting in code

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm trying to use SAS 9.4 data hash obj.
Some code here:

```
data joined;
    if 0 then set data1 data2;
    if _n_=1 then do;
        declare hash merger (dataset:'data2');
        merger.definekey('some_key');
        merger.definedata('col1','col2');
        merger.definedone();
    end;
    set data1;
    if merger.find(key:some_key)=0 then output;
run;
```

Now i want to make it macro played like:

```
%let list=2 3 4 5;
 data joined;
        if 0 then set data1 data_&i.;
        if _n_=1 then do;
            declare hash merger (dataset:'data_&i.');
            merger.definekey('some_key');
            merger.definedata('col1','col2');
            merger.definedone();
        end;
        set data1;
        if merger.find(key:some_key)=0 then output;
  run;
```

But as i see the problem is quotes around here:

```
dataset:'data_&i.'
```

How to convert this string for sas code?
in python i can do smth like str(data[i]);

Comment: You don't actually have to do this in a macro, by the way; you can simply construct the hash arguments as strings in normal data step code.

Comment: In fact this is just for example, real program is more massive.
I wanted to know the method of sending sas macro variables to text.
But ofc thank u for attention.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double quotes and the macro variable will resolve.

```
declare hash merger (dataset:"data_&i.");
```